# In Meteor.js will a stub's database writes always be completed as soon as the stub finishes?

Tags: javascript, meteor, callback

When calling a method in Meteor that is client and server side there is the simulated [stub](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call) run. I assume the stub will run synchronously on the same line as the method is called and will issue writes to the simulated minimongo database.

Now my question is: after having called a method, can I rely on the stub's db writes being available right away in the client side minimongo db? More precisely with "right away" I mean:

1. Will the client side db be updated (by the stub) on the next code line after the method call?
2. Will the client side db be updated (by the stub) if I issue a `Meteor.defer` on the next code line at the time the deferred function runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writes to minimongo are synchronous, so the answer is "yes" assuming your method stub only contains synchronous operations. Let's take this example:

```
Meteor.methods({
  gotime: function() {
    Posts.insert({text: 'hello'});
  }
});
```

Now, somewhere else on the client:

```
// call the stub method (note there is no callback passed)
Meteor.call('gotime');
// the new document will be available here
post = Posts.findOne();
```